# Angularjs Generate Table dynamically based on column property

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to generate table in angularjs with column property but data are not displayed based on it's header.
here is my code.

```
    $scope.headers = [{
     "order": 1,
     "width": 0,
     "label": "ID",
     "data": "id",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": true
   },
   {
     "order": 2,
     "width": 120,
     "label": "Last Name",
     "data": "lastName",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": true
   },
   {
     "order": 3,
     "width": 129,
     "label": "First Name",
     "data": "firstName",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": false
   },
   {
     "order": 4,
     "width": 200,
     "label": "Email Address",
     "data": "email",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": false
   },
   {
     "order": 5,
     "width": 120,
     "label": "Phone Number",
     "data": "phoneNumber",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": true
   },
   {
     "order": 6,
     "width": 80,
     "label": "Username",
     "data": "username",
     "type": "string",
     "visible": true
   },
   {
     "order": 7,
     "width": 100,
     "label": "Last Login",
     "data": "lastLoginDate",
     "type": "date",
     "visible": true
   }
 ];

 $scope.users = [{
     "id": "1",
     "lastName": "Test1",
     "firstName": "Test",
     "email": "test1@example.com",
     "phoneNumber": "(555) 111-0001",
     "username": "ttest1",
     "lastLoginDate": "12/28/2012 3:51 PM"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "lastName": "Test2",
     "firstName": "Test",
     "email": "test2@example.com",
     "phoneNumber": "(555) 222-0002",
     "username": "ttest2",
     "lastLoginDate": "12/28/2012 3:52 PM"
   },
   {
     "id": "3",
     "lastName": "Test3",
     "firstName": "Test",
     "email": "test3@example.com",
     "phoneNumber": "(555) 333-0003",
     "username": "ttest3",
     "lastLoginDate": "12/28/2012 3:53 PM"
   },
   {
     "id": "4",
     "lastName": "Test4",
     "firstName": "Test",
     "email": "test4@example.com",
     "phoneNumber": "(555) 444-0004",
     "username": "ttest4",
     "lastLoginDate": "12/28/2012 3:54 PM"
   },
   {
     "id": "5",
     "lastName": "Test5",
     "firstName": "Test",
     "email": "test5@example.com",
     "phoneNumber": "(555) 555-0005",
     "username": "ttest5",
     "lastLoginDate": "12/28/2012 3:55 PM"
   }

 ];
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fire first loop on table row and second loop on table data. Table row loop is for users array and Table Data Loop for headers array. Please check on example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-zuljsb?file=home%2Fhome.html)

Here is the HTML code :

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header.label}}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td ng-repeat="header in headers">
        {{user[header.data]}}
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="column in headers">{{column.label}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td ng-repeat="column in headers">
                {{user[column.data]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.